# Is it possible to make one css or js in common to all my Lightning web components?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, css

Here is my situation, I have two (and soon more) LWC, inside each component, I have the classic : html, css, js and xml.

In my case, the first LWC is having many css properties in common with the other LWC : color of buttons, same font, etc.

I want to have a global CSS out and to that make all LWC share some common properties. How to do that ?

Same think for JS.

Additional information : I am using full-custom classes css (and my own js), I do not use any element from the lightning Library.

Comment: It is possible now - [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/315665/70823)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest mechanism for sharing JS and CSS code between LWCs across a single project is essentially create an LWC for each (the JS and the CSS).

Each LWC contains *just the code artifact for the JS or CSS code*.

In other words, they're LWC's without HTML templates. The one will have your XML metadata [descriptor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_meta_file) and a JS module, the other will have the XML descriptor and the CSS file.

There are instructions for how to construct and consume these in the LWC documentation with an example each for [CSS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_css_share) and for [JS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_share_code).

There is an example of this in the LWC Recipes sample app with the [component](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/miscSharedJavaScript/miscSharedJavaScript.js) importing JS from another [module](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/mortgage/mortgage.js) in the project.

Reading your comment above, I'd say that the best architecture for you is a larger scale library that encapsulates all your CSS assets (and the images that go with them) into a component that's consumed across your project. You might even want to look at packaging it as its own unmanaged package so you can simply install it using `sfdx force:package:install`. That way, the entire CSS library is its own project with its own development lifecycle.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

> To share CSS style rules, create a module that contains only a CSS
> file. Import the style rules from that CSS file into the CSS files of
> other Lightning web components.
>
> You can import style rules from multiple CSS modules. The imported
> style rules are applied to the template just like non-imported style
> rules. Lightning Web Components supports the CSS cascade algorithm.

Create a Lightning web component that contains only a CSS file.

```
cssLibrary
   ├──cssLibrary.css
   └──cssLibrary.js-meta.xml
```

In the CSS file of another Lightning web component, import the style rules

```
/* myComponent.css */

@import 'cssLibrary.css';

/* Other style rules for myComponent here */
```

[Refer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_css_share) | [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/wCqAqcjqC/5/edit)

Comment: Thank you Rahul, yes, i forgot to say it, but all my lwc are custom (all css classes are cutom) i do not use lightning graphics

Comment: @BestAboutMe Actually there is a better way. The static resource you should use only when you want to override some standard component CSS. The recommended way is you can create one component as CSS library and refer that in all other components.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you again, I wanted to import of cssLibrary.css inside another lwc (other thant the app module on the Playground) but it doesn't work, is it possible to import same css in many lwc ?

Comment: @BestAboutMe Yes, it is unlike the LWC in Salesforce, playground needs exact relative address for the CSS file

Comment: I see, but in my real project, I'm having troubles with the new LWC (css library), the error I have is : "Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle sharedStyle" means I need to add xml meta to this LWC and not only a css file

Comment: yes you need meta xml as well

Comment: Did you try this? I added this and the XML and it doesn't work

Comment: I tried sharing CSS and it worked, what you have tried so far can you add another question? @CarlosIribar also looks like you have downvoted the answer, I don't see a reason for this.

Comment: Your example without the xml file doesn't even let the component deploy (Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle), if i add the xml file iI can't do the deploy either (No base file for markup: // c: css), could you confirm me that in a scratch org for example, using api version 49, does this work for you without problems?

Comment: I did not use it in scratch org. I have used it in the sandbox. It works for me even with V49. @CarlosIribar

Comment: @Pirata21 I did not try it in scratch org, but it worked in the sandbox with v49 and 48

Comment: The guidelines for creating the CSS-only component and referencing it in the CSS of other components are correct. However, I experienced the same problems that others reported with deploying the components that imported the CSS. I discovered that the CSS-only component MUST be deployed as part of the same package as the components that import it. I used Workbench to do this.

Comment: Do you mean the component which imported the shared CSS and the component which holds the CSS need to be deployed together? @womanwhodevs

Comment: Yes, @rahulgawale

Comment: This doesn't work in sandbox keep getting no module found, if any one knows how to resolve this then please post on this thread https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/not-able-to-import-css-in-lwc-no-module-named-markup thank you in anticipation

Comment: @gs650x There is a bug in the Summer 2020 release, so you need to deploy two components together, common CSS component and the component which is consuming the common CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the solutions mentioned till now, another way to achieve this would be create a static resource and keep your entire css style rules and images in it. You will have to load static resource once in the outer most component i.e. parent component. Styling will get applied to child components when they are rendered.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a new community, you can always use the community's global css.
Beware that this solution could overwrite any local css styling set on the component.

for more information:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm